# Do silencers reduce the amount of damage that guns do?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I see that on the gun stats that adding a suppressor on any gun reduces both the range and the damage bar what does it actually do to the guns performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [The Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Suppressor)

> As a disadvantage, the Silencer either reduces the range at which weapons do their maximum damage, damage of the weapon as a whole, or the damage done by the weapon at its longest range depending on what weapon the Silencer is used with.

In Call of Duty Ghosts Silencer reduces the range in guns which means that the drop-off damage is reduces. To most guns this is by -25% range.

For Example:
According to [Symthic](http://symthic.com/cod-ghosts-weapon-info?w=Honey_Badger):
The damage of the Honey Badger drops off to 20 at 33 meters without a silencer.
With a silencer and the -25% range reduction the dropoff instead of 33 meters turns to 24.75 meters. Which will change the amount of shots from 4 to 5 between 24.75 - 33 meters. 
To many it would seem like a damage reduction; because it is but it only reduce the range. The gun will never drop below 20 damage per shot.

Answer (score 1):

The silencer only lowers the Max effective range, so it does less damage at longer ranges. But it hardly changes any of the Sniper Rifles Max Effective Range.

Answer (score 0):

They stop you from appearing as a dot on there radar when firing and you don't hear as much noise from your gun it also lowers the damage and range your bullets do

Comment: ... Of course it stops you from appearing.

Comment: Also not really anwsering the question.